# c#/wpf ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent exception

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have an c#/wpf application with a set of `UserControl`s and got an error when starting debugging in visual studio 2015 when showing a specific `UserControl`(both in debug and release settings):

> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '16' and line position '6'.

Line 16 in the xaml file of the `UserControl`that causes the exception to be thrown is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
```

The `_innerException` of the thrown exception states:

> {"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'  Key being added: 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'"}

This seems quite strange and I do not know how to tackle this. I have googled for any clues but they are mostly relevant for specific plugins like telerik and such. Many solutions I have found seems rather "accidental".

Does anyone have any ideas?

(using visual studio 2015)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found I had two "keyless" `<style></style>` tags in the `<UserControl.Resources>` that caused the problem. Merging these corrected the error. (too bad visual studio does not highlight this as a problem)